Door frame coming out because of storm door
I have installed a door closer for storm door about a year ago. Recently I noticed that it generated pressure on door frame and there is gap formed between the door and frame. I feel like this is because of door closer pressure or something.
Any idea how to fix this ?
Do they generally always put two door closer.

I'm having trouble understanding what the picture is supposed to show us.  The gap?  Also, if you want help making the door closer not create a gap, you should show us a picture of the door closer.

Hey I am sorry if you are not able to understand this. I just posted another picture which shows the issue.I don’t know what this called but it is the wood to which storm door is attached. This wood is started coming out.

Maybe you need more screws?

I have also seen storm door closers pull on and even rip off the door frame piece. This is because the screws of the closer plate only grab the door frame, not the wall structure behind it. If the door frame piece is weak or only a surface mount jamb edge, then the frame piece is not strong enough to handle the pull of the closer.
If your wall structure behind the door frame is wood or other material compatible with being screwed into, you can replace the small door closer plate screws with longer screws that will grab the wall structure behind the door frame.
Remove one screw at a time, replace with the longer screw, and don't drive the new screw in further than the plate sits when the door is closed and the door frame is in its proper at-rest position.
Note: Many door frames have a gap between the frame and the wall to allow for shimming the frame to be plumb and level in often out-of-plumb/level wall openings. The longer screws should not squeeze this gap smaller than it was when the door was installed. If you can remove the door trim and access this gap, you can insert suitable shimming to fill the gap behind the storm door closer plate, so the longer screws can be tightened harder without squeezing the gap.

Thank you. I feel like this trim will come out soon if I don’t take any action soon. Do you think adding one more door closer at top will minimize the pressure on trim ?

I suspect it will double the pull on the door. Each will pull the same amount. A few long screws are less expensive than another closer.

Not sure how adding longer screws for door closer will solve this problem. Trim where storm door is attached started coming out as door closer generates pressure on storm door when it holds the storm door.

Can you please update your question pictures to indicate exactly which part is moving which direction? It could be possible the failures I have seen that longer screws would solve may not be the failure you're having.
